# How to make a GridPane right of BorderPane closeable?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have code in the form:

```
<BorderPane>   
... 
<right>
    <GridPane>
        ...
    </GridPane>
</right>
...
</BorderPane>
```

Obviously, now the GridPane takes a big space right of my BorderPane. What I'd like to do is add a button (or another element) that minimizes and maximizes the GridPane, so it's only fully in the view of the user when it is really needed. How can I easily achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want by setting the Visible and Managed properties of your GridPane off and on.  The centre of the BorderPane will automatically expand to take over the entire width of the BorderPane.  "Managed" controls whether or not the layout manager will leave space for the node, so if you just turn Visible off, then you'll have an unused area the size of your GridPane on the right.  The following code demonstrates it, I put the buttons in a VBox with a border around it so that you can see how it expands:

```
public class ResizeRight extends BorderPane {

    public ResizeRight() {
        Button openButton = new Button("Open");
        Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.addRow(0, new Text("This is just some text"));
        gridPane.addRow(1, new Text("This is just some more text"));
        VBox vbox = new VBox(10, openButton, closeButton);
        vbox.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK,
                BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT)));
        setCenter(vbox);
        setRight(gridPane);
        setPadding(new Insets(10));
        openButton.setOnAction(evt -> {
            gridPane.setVisible(true);
            gridPane.setManaged(true);
        });
        closeButton.setOnAction(evt -> {
            gridPane.setVisible(false);
            gridPane.setManaged(false);
        });
    }
}
```

Run it from something like this:

```
public class Sample1 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new ResizeRight(), 300, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```